# Iphone masking colors: Remove background color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, masking

I have a series of avatars; each has a hot pink background of RGB:255,0,255.

Rather than going through every avatar, and manually removing the pink background; is there a way to make Objective C remove the background (masking it) for me?

An example of an avatar follows:

[alt text http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/2645/bluegem.png](http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/2645/bluegem.png)

One thing I am concerned about is that the masking is done on the fly, and may cost memory; is this something I should be concerned about?

Additionally, let's say I put the avatars in a spritesheet; could I apply the mask once and work with that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

see function CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors. I think this is what you need. See reference:
[Masking an Image With Color](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you added the buttons programatically you could set a global NSArray and `addObject:yourButton` each time you make an avatar button, then when you want to remove the background do this:

```
for (UIButton *custom in globalButtonArray) {
    custom.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Comment: Just thinking acctually you would need an NSMutableArray... so you could add the buttons. :)

Comment: Why should this work? The image have opaque pink areas. They completely cover everything that's underneath. Changing the background color of some UI element will have no effect. And why are you introducing buttons? What for?

Comment: Ah... i dunno why I said buttons, I meant UIImageView - apologies. Similarly, I just assumed that the purple background was programatically added. Otherwise I would assume the auhor would have called them "pink areas". I misunderstood.

Comment: I still haven't been able to remove the background color.  CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors does not have any source code examples,  unlike the rest of the documentation on that page.

Comment: can you not just open the images in photoshop and make them pngs with transparency.